# Select more than one class name in the same obj

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I'm trying to make a tab filter by jquery.
I want to ask how to select only div has class type1 also has class type2

```
  <div class="type1 type2"> </div> //select this one
  <div class="type1 type4"> </div>
```

and check the selector length if they found

```
   var typeselect = $('select the div above');
   if(typeselect.length > 0 ){} found it
   else
```

Comment: `$('.type1.type2')`

Comment: read about all jQuery selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`class selector`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) like below,

```
var typeselect = $('div.type1.type2');
```

Comment: Please help me if this is correct, the classtype will receive an id,
var classtype = $(obj).find('a').attr('href');
var filter = $('.sec5row'+classtype);

Comment: @pexichdu What will be the value of `classType` ?

Comment: it will be received an id, I want to select the element has class name="sec5row" id="abc", abc is received in classtype

Comment: @pexichdu Hmm if it is an id then `var filter = $('.sec5row #'+ classtype);` this will be a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

You use `.type1.type2` (note: no space) to select only elements that have both classes. See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for more about selectors.

This is just an application of the general principal that selector elements can be *combined*. That is, you can combine an ID seletor like `#foo` with a class selector like `.bar` to be `#foo.bar` (only find the element if it has both the ID and the class). Or combining a class selector with an attribute selector: `.foo[data-special]` (only find the element if it has the class and that attribute). Or combining a tag selector with a pseudoclass: `div:hover`.

Comment: thank you for noting about spacing